# How to return rows that contain certain combinations of strings?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want all rows that contain `hafa`, `h&aring;fa`, `haf&aring;`, or `h&aring;f&aring;`. What SQL statement will accomplish this goal?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE chamorro LIKE ???`

I don't think `h[a&aring;]f[a&aring;]` works in this case.

I want to know if there's an alternate way to write the `WHERE` clause rather than concatenating `OR` statements together.

Comment: ...condition1 OR condition2 OR ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `like` statements:

```
select *
from table
where chamorro like '%hafa%' or chamorro like '%h&aring;fa%' or
      chamorro like '%haf&aring;%' or chamorro like '%h&aring;f&aring;%';
```